# C++ memory layout of static vs function static vs member function static

Tags: c++, memory, static

Considering 3 different static arrays in some Class.cpp file:

```
static char array0[8];

/*static*/ char Class::s_array1[8]; //static declared in Header Class.h

void Class::DoStuff()
{
    static char f_array2[8];
}
```

Is it clearly defined whether the 3 arrays will be contiguous in memory relative to each other, and in which order? (Or does it depend on the compiler/platform)

Comment: You can, by getting their memory addresses, and compare/sort them ... but what is the goal ? what do you try to do ?

Comment: I mean is it predictable, or does it depend on compiler /platform etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are always contiguous in memory, but it is not defined where they will end up relative to each other.

Answer (score 2):

This is fully compiler and platform dependent. In the case it runs on a Linux platform, you can *guess* that these arrays will be in the .bss section.

Obviously, each array is contiguous in memory. This is mandatory.